Blazebit persistence and jakarta migration
I've just updated my Quarkus project from version 2 to version 3, one big change that they made is the fact that they now use jakarta domain instead of javax.
Obviously i used their CLI to update the project, as suggested in this guide: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/wiki/Migration-Guide-3.0~
However i'm now getting this error with BlazeBit persistence:
"The method create(EntityManager, Class) from the type CriteriaBuilderFactory refers to the missing type EntityManager"
package it.scdn.sale.repository;

import com.blazebit.persistence.CriteriaBuilder;
import com.blazebit.persistence.CriteriaBuilderFactory;
import com.blazebit.persistence.view.EntityViewManager;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.persistence.PersistenceContext;

public abstract class CriteriaRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager em;

    @Inject
    protected CriteriaBuilderFactory cbf;

    @Inject
    protected EntityViewManager evm;

    /**
     * Get the entity manager.
     *
     * @return entity manager object
     */
    public EntityManager getEm() {
        return em;
    }

    /**
     * Set entity manager.
     *
     * @param em entity manager object
     */
    public void setEm(final EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

    /**
     * Get criteria builder factory object.
     *
     * @return cbf
     */
    public CriteriaBuilderFactory getCbf() {
        return cbf;
    }

    /**
     * Set criteria builder factory object.
     *
     * @param cbf cbf object
     */
    public void setCbf(final CriteriaBuilderFactory cbf) {
        this.cbf = cbf;
    }

    /**
     * Get entity view manager.
     *
     * @return evm object
     */
    public EntityViewManager getEvm() {
        return evm;
    }

    /**
     * Set entity view manager.
     *
     * @param evm evm object
     */
    public void setEvm(final EntityViewManager evm) {
        this.evm = evm;
    }

    /**
     * Factory for criteria API.
     *
     * @param tClass tClass param
     * @param <T> class type
     * @return custom criteria from the TClass
     */
    protected <T> CriteriaBuilder<T> initCriteria(final Class<T> tClass) {
        return cbf.create(em, tClass);
    }
}

While looking at the source code i noticed that the create method requires a javax entityManager, could this the reason why its not finding it? Is there a workaround or am i missing something?
    /**
     * Like {@link CriteriaBuilderFactory#create(javax.persistence.EntityManager, java.lang.Class, java.lang.String)} but with the alias
     * equivalent to the camel cased result of what {@link Class#getSimpleName()} of the result class returns.
     *
     * @param entityManager The entity manager to use for the criteria builder
     * @param resultClass The result class of the query
     * @param <T> The type of the result class
     * @return A new criteria builder
     */
    public <T> CriteriaBuilder<T> create(EntityManager entityManager, Class<T> resultClass);

This is the dependecy i have in my pom:
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus.platform</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-blaze-persistence-bom</artifactId>
  <version>3.14.2</version>
  <type>pom</type>
  <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>


Blaze-Persistence has separate modules for jakarta support. I am surprised though that the BOM does not contain these.

Try reimporting your project or check if you maybe have an explicit dependency with an old version somewhere. The POM clearly shows that the jakarta artifacts are to be used: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/quarkus/platform/quarkus-blaze-persistence-bom/3.14.2/quarkus-blaze-persistence-bom-3.14.2.pom
